# SSAS - Calculation in DSV or in view from data source

Tags: ssas

This wasn't an easy question to Google, a lot of word overlap.

My table has a column with a date. I'd like another column that is a calculation on that date. I can do this with a Named Calculation on the dsv. Or, I could do this in the view from the data source that feeds this table into SSAS. Trying to figure out which would be better.

This calculated column will be for a dimension attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Adding calculations either in DSV or in a view do not have much difference, it is just a choice, where you wish to maintain your SQL code. You can take a decision based on, which approach is best suited for you, from maintenance point of view.

following link can be helpful: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/42215fd0-9cc4-4463-b739-de116f1d38be/named-calculations-vs-calculated-members?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I push as much as I can into the SQL View because it is easier to maintain than having to make changes to my cube. The view is meant to present an abstraction of the underlying data in a manner that can easily be consumed by SSAS.

Using your example, let us assume that you put the calculation in the DSV. Over time your source data grows and the processing time for your cube increases dramatically. If you now decided to move it into the view, you have to redeploy your cube and deploy a modification to the SQL views to now support your column.

However, if you put it in the view to begin with, any modifications that you want to make will not require you to redeploy your cube. So, if in the future, you decide that the calculation is too costly, and that persisting the actual calculation within the base tables is the best approach - you can do this with relative ease as long as you maintain the view contract expected by the cube.